# change the direction of the directional light in 3js

Tags: web3js

i want to change the direction of the directional light from pointing to the origin to point it to another point in space, however it seems to not be working. i used the lookat thing but its still point to the origin.to check where it points i have added a dlight helper but it keeps pointing to the origin

```
const directionallight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF,0.8);
const colorHex = '#ffea00';
const color = new THREE.Color(colorHex);
directionallight.color = color;

const targetPoint = new THREE.Vector3(-50,50,3);
directionallight.lookAt(targetPoint);

directionallight.castShadow = true;
directionallight.position.set(-20,5,3);
scene.add(directionallight);

const dlighthelper = new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(directionallight,5);
scene.add(dlighthelper);
```